# Variable not being set correctly; how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my JQuery to select one of the navigation links—based on the page that I'm on—and then I want it to move it to the top of the list.

This is the HTML of my navigation bar:

```
<nav>
    <ul id=nav>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="skillsets.php">Skillsets</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.php"><icon>Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the JQuery I'm using to try and reorder the list:

```
var page = document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ul = $('nav').children('ul'),
        li = ul.children('li'),
        href = $('a[href*='+page+']');
        //move element to top
        ul.prepend(href.parent());
});
```

It isn't working and I would assume that it's because the `href` variable isn't being set correctly. `alert(href);` and `alert(href.parent());` output nothing.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding quotes around page variable? `href = $('a[href*=\''+page+'\']');`

Comment: as Justinas Jurciukonis mentions, should use quotes around the value part as there might be some regular expression characters in the page path (ie: . ? etc), should be getting an error in your console about `unrecognized expression`

Comment: @JustinasJurciukonis That worked; but why do I need to add the two back-slash's and parentheses?

Comment: you dont you could have just use `"` instead of back-slashing(escaping) the single quotes. Escaping the single quote just lets you use single quotes within a string delimited by single quotes. `$('a[href*="'+page+'"]');` would do the same thing without needing escaping

Comment: @PatrickEvans Then why do I need to escape? (Why wouldn't `$('a[href*=''+page+'']');` work?)

Comment: @LarryK, because its how strings work, you need a starting and ending quote to delimit the characters in a string. With it that way you would be basically making 3 strings, 'a[href*=', '+page+', and ']'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var href = $('a[href*="'+page+'"]');
```

**EDIT**

Also, you can write a bit shorter with child selectors:

```
var ul = $('nav > ul'),
    href = ul.find('> li a[href*="' + page + '"]');
ul.prepend(href.parent());
```

Comment: If I did that, wouldn't I then just use `ul.prepend(href);` and not `ul.prepend(href.parent());`?

Comment: @LarryK, no href would be the anchor tag, while you want to move the li tag, which the href.parent() gets.

Comment: @PatrickEvans It looks like the `href` variable is selecting the list element (with the specification of where it links) though.

Comment: @LarryK, you need to look up CSS selectors, `> li a` means get any `a` tag in any direct descendant `li`

Comment: @PatrickEvans Since I have set `li = ul.children('li')` wouldn't it be a little bit better to do `href = li.find('a[href*="'+page+'"]');`?

Comment: @LarryK that would be an extra step, he is just cutting out the need to make and use a `li` variable.

Answer (score 1):

As @user3064914 said, you missed '#', but you missed quotes either:

```
<ul id = "nav">
```

Comment: no he didnt miss the #, again he is grabbing the nav tag not the tag with id nav

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thank you Patrick, I've had to point this out to a lot of people.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, it will work.**

```
<script>
    var page = document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];    

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
            var href = $('a[href='+'"'+page+'"'+']').parent();
            var parent = $("#nav");    
            var childToMoveLast = href.remove();
            parent.prepend(childToMoveLast);

    });

 </script>
```

Here is the HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul id='nav'>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="skillsets.php">Skillsets</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.php"><icon>Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```